# Ethernet signals

Tags: ethernet

I have an end of an ethernet cable but I don't know where it goes. I want to see if it is connected to a device at the other end.

Looking at the pinout you have a TX+/TX- and an RX+/RX- pair of wires. From Google I have seen something about auto-negotiation and I believed this was the way to detect it, however when connected to an oscilloscope, I can't see anything.

Is there a specific way in which to detect if the cable is plugged in? (Thinking of using voltage if I could see some.) Is it possible to detect this? Well, it must be, because how do hubs/switches detect if something is plugged in?

Are there any resources which can help?

EDIT:
I have tried using a scope connected directly to the pins, using DC blocking capacitors, and a transformerless differential line receiver but I havent had any change in the bogus 200V reading im getting.

Has anyone done this before? Is there a circuit which is known to work?

Comment: Doesn't it go into the ether?

Comment: one end goes into hub the other is loose, how can i detect the hub's presence through the disconnected end of the cable?

Comment: I'd just connect it to a switch and see if one of the lights goes on.

Comment: Simon, a switch would be good BUT this project requires me not to use a switch (theres a bigger project behind it)

Comment: No, connect it to check for the connection, and then disconnect it later.

Comment: fuzzy i know what you meant but what im doing is trying to make it automatic from a micro controller. the controller will be pluged into 24 connections and it has to poll them to find the ones connected and disconnected

Comment: Hmm, seems like you can use the TX and RX to do that, depending on which end you want to measure. I mean, they are differential signaling, no? So just check for opposite logic levels. Use an XOR gate.

Comment: fuzzy I understand that bit - but when I try to get the levels I get nothing at all. the hub is powered but I cant get any signals the other end. The main question is what are the signals on the tx pair and how to wire it up.

Comment: The signals are **differential**, which means that when a device is connected, it will drive the inverting and noninverting signal lines opposite. So basically, if you get nothing, a device is not connected, if you get opposite logic levels, then something is connected. What you are seeing is normal, as only one device is connected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15891/discussion-between-fuzzyhair2-and-noliver92).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to determine whether the other end of the cable is connected to a device.

Assuming this is point to point ethernet with RJ-45 connectors, you can look at the DC resistance between the wires of a pair.  This type of ethernet is transformer coupled, so will have a low DC resistance.  If nothing is connected to the other end, then the lines will be open and have a infinite resistance.

Or, you can look for link pulses.  These are pulses occasionally sent by each end so that the other end knows there is a device out there.

Comment: I was looking at the link pulses but I can not pick them up (think im connecting to oscilliscope wrong)

Comment: @NoLiver92 - add a diagram or at least through explanation of your connection to the question.  You might also find this useful: http://www.fpga4fun.com/10BASE-T4.html though if I recall some of that plays "try it today pragmatic" games with capacitive rather than transformer coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet over RJ45 is sent using a differential signalling. This means that the wires in each of the two pairs is driven to opposite logic levels. The voltage levels are ±0.85V.

When a device is disconnected, there will be an absence of this voltage. So what you can do is to check to see whether a differential signal exists on the TX pair or RX pair (depending on which end you want to see).

http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~ross/Ethernet/protocol.htm

Comment: Note that this signal is only AC.  You will never see a DC voltage between pairs with something like a voltmeter due to the average always being 0.

Answer (score -2):

Routers and switches have a uni or inni connection. Dcn rl-ime the correct way to test all cables and switches routers Etc is by sending a modulated signal set to modulation of switches etc and see if you get any jitter in packets. Need a test set to put on both ends near and far. If your just connecting a home router get a small fluke tester for basic cat5 cables and follow directions in the box